# Understanding a TypeError "Not a fucntion" in Node

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

I looked around and while this seems to be a common error I can't really find an answer to what I am doing wrong.

```
    const express = require('express')
    const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql')
    const app = express()
    
    app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({
        graphiql: true
    }))
    app.listen(5000., () => console.log('Server is Running'))
```

Whenever I compile that I get this error...

```
    app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({
                        ^
    
    TypeError: expressGraphQL is not a function
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Node\Project_GraphQL\server.js:5:21)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
        at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
        at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I'm trying to follow along with this video here and near as I can tell I have copied it line for line....

https://youtu.be/ZQL7tL2S0oQ?t=565

What have I misunderstood and done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the last version, express-graphql return an object, in this case you should use:

```
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql')
```

or in your code

```
app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL.graphqlHTTP({
    graphiql: true
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see the npm docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-graphql). `graphqlHTTP`  is the function which is exported form the module (it is using Object [destructring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#:%7E:text=The%20destructuring%20assignment%20syntax%20is,from%20objects%2C%20into%20distinct%20variables.)).

So your Code Should look like below

```
const express = require('express');
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
 
const app = express();
 
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP({
   
    graphiql: true,
  }),
);
 
app.listen(5000., () => console.log('Server is Running'))
```